# Acumatica Automation steps unable to add simple print action or report

Tags: acumatica

Business requirement is to add a simple action that when an order goes into a Backorder status, a user can click actions > send backorder notification.

I tried to accomplish this via Automation Steps.

Modify existing screen/step
Sales Order enter screen
SO Backorder step

Added action
Name Send Backorder Report
Flow on success do notification

The result was that no option appeared in the menu. I also tried various other steps. At one point the menu option appeared and worked, but then 5 minutes later disappeared

I also tried to do a report instead of an action and set field @reportID and so on as the technical tuesday article describes.

In all cases I am unable to make a simple menu option appear in any status on the sales order screen.

Images

```
https://www.screencast.com/t/6dTYz4VhB0J1
https://www.screencast.com/t/NeDP2SOEN1e
https://www.screencast.com/t/IQvFMF4KQhl
```

Comment: To add a new action, I suggest skipping automation steps and define a custom action button, see http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2017/07/actions-and-primary-view.html

Comment: I tested the report button guide this morning (http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2017/08/adding-new-report-button-on-invoices.html) and it works. Can you put an image of your automation step and add your graph extension code ?

Comment: I added 3 images.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I was using this guide previously which for me, doesn't appear to work

https://www.acumatica.com/blog/technical-tuesday-adding-items-to-the-inquiries-and-reports-menus-part1/